# Programmatically save as PowerPoint 2007 (pptx), from PowerPoint 2003

Tags: vba, powerpoint, openxml

I need to be able to save Presentations (programatically)  in PowerPoint 2003 as OpenXML (".pptx").
I installed the Microsoft Office Compatibility Pack. This indeed allows me to perform "Save as PowerPoint 2007 Presentation" from PowerPoint 2003.

How can I do this programmatically? (e.g. VBA)

I tried `Presentation.SaveAs`:
While there is no inherent `PpSaveAsFileType` enum value in PowerPoint 2003 for `ppSaveAsOpenXMLPresentation`, I made a program which prints the `PpSaveAsFileType` values and found out that during run-time, `ppSaveAsOpenXMLPresentation = 24`.

However, I tried:
`SaveAs(@"c:\temp\saveas\pupik.pptx", (PpSaveAsFileType) ((int) 24), MsoTriState.msoTrue);`

And got an "Invalid Enumeration Value" Exception

Any ideas how to make this work?

(PS - I am aware that this question was already asked by several people on the web, but no solutions were offered.)

Thanks,
Arie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit > Some grammar

AFAIK the pptx format does not support macro-enabled presentations, so if your code is in the presentation you are trying to save, it will not work.

I don't have Excel 2003 at hand now, but **if the Compatibility Pack enabled the option "pptx"** in the Configuration Dialog, Default Save Format, **and you are trying to save ANOTHER presentation** I guess you can if you use something like:

```
 MyOtherPresentation.SaveAs "C:\Mypres", ppSaveAsDefault
```

Please note that this may work only if the presentation had not been saved before in ppt format

**EDIT**

If the above doesn't work, you could try a different approach. Save the file in the old format and the call a conversion program:

**ppcnvcom.exe**
  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027102/why-does-wordconv-exe-randomly-return-14-when-called-from-a-net-windows-service) for an example (using wordconv.exe, but essentially the same)
  Be sure to have all the office upgrades installed, because if not the program ends 
  reporting no error and doing nothing.

**ofc**
  See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179019%28office.12%29.aspx) for instructions
  And [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/oxmlsdk/thread/8becabda-0014-4e06-8354-5f576bf46595) for a good discussion

HTH!

Comment: Thanks belisarius, however what I need is to load ".ppt" and save as ".pptx", so unfortunately "save as default" would not work.

BTW - my code is not in the presentation I am trying to save, it is a C# VSTO program, so I don't have a problem with Macros.

Comment: @Arie Livshin Perhaps it may work if you save it with another name. Care to try?

Comment: I do save it to another name than the original.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll do this externally as you suggest.

Answer (score 3):

A trick is to modify the default save format of the application in the Registry, then save and finally to restore the original save format again.

The relevant key is

```
Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\PowerPoint\Options
```

Create a `DWORD` value with name `DefaultFormat` and set it to 0x21 to save as PPTX.

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    ...
    using (PptxSaver pptxSaver = new PptxSaver())
    {
        presentation.SaveAs("sample.pptx")
    }
    ...
}

class PptxSaver : IDisposable
{
    private const string OptionKey = @"Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\PowerPoint\Options";
    private const string OptionValue = "DefaultFormat";        
    private const int SaveFormatPptx = 0x21;

    private int oldFormat;

    public PptxSaver()
    {
        using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(OptionKey, true))
        {
            oldFormat = (int)key.GetValue(OptionValue, -1);
            key.SetValue(OptionValue, SaveFormatPptx, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Delete the value
        using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(OptionKey, true))
        {
            if (oldFormat == -1)
            {
                key.DeleteValue(OptionValue);
            }
            else
            {
                key.SetValue(OptionValue, oldFormat);
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: @Arie Livshin This is a clever approach! To manipulate the registry in VBA there are several options. Look for examples in http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming/531053-read-registry-keys-and-possibly-write.html And you could try it manually with regedit before programming.

Answer (score 0):

I used ppcnvcom.exe but note that unlike a considerable amount of posts I used only the -oice switch without the -nme switch

Answer (score 0):

For VBA this works:

```
Sub TestSaveas()
  SaveAs "c:\somefilepath\"
End sub

Private Sub SaveAs(fp As String)
   Dim dlgSaveAs As FileDialog
   Dim strMyFile As String

   Set dlgSaveAs = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
   With dlgSaveAs
       .InitialFileName = fp
       If .Show = -1 Then
           strMyFile = .SelectedItems(1)
           Application.ActivePresentation.SaveAs strMyFile
           'MsgBox strMyFile
           ''-- save your file to strMyFile here
       Else
           MsgBox "File not saved"
       End If
   End With
   dlgSaveAs.Execute
   Set dlgSaveAs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I got around the problem recently using:

```
Presentation.SaveCopyAs "c:\temp\saveas\pupik.pptx"
```

instead of `SaveAs`. Works well, regardless wether the original is in ppt- or pptx-format.

(I could not get the registry-change method mentioned to work for me without reopening the presentation.)