# PowerPoint 2003 with PowerPoint 2007 compatibility pack save as pptx

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint, compatibility, office-interop

I want to create and save a PowerPoint presentation as PPTX using PowerPoint 2003 PIA, with office 2007 compatibility pack installed? Is it possible how do i achieve this?

```
 PropertyValues.PptPresObj.SaveAs(_pptTemporaryFilePath, PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsPresentation, _
                                      MsoTriState.msoFalse)
```

There is no option in the enumerator to save as pptx ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically save as PowerPoint 2007 (pptx), from PowerPoint 2003 ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145396/programmatically-save-as-powerpoint-2007-pptx-from-powerpoint-2003)

Comment: how do i delete these thread?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

It is possible to do that by clicking at Save As and choosing Microsoft PowerPoint 2003 or 2007 Presentation.

Comment: OP wants to do it programmatically.