# Mass converting .doc files to .docx

Tags: python, ms-word

i have around 1.2 Million .doc Files (all around 50kb big) in need of conversion to .docx. So far i tried using Word via win32com interface for Python, but it is really really slow (1-2 Files per Second). Is there any faster way to accomplish this?

Edit:
Code im using so far:

```
def convert_doc_to_docx():
    dir = "sampledir"
    word = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
    word.visible = 0
    globData = glob.iglob(dir + "*.doc")
    totalFiles = len([name for name in os.listdir(dir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir, name))])
    for i, doc in enumerate(globData):
        in_file = os.path.abspath(doc)
        wb = word.Documents.Open(in_file)
        out_file = os.path.abspath(doc + "x")
        wb.SaveAs2(out_file, FileFormat=16)  # file format for docx
        wb.Close()
        os.remove(in_file)
        print(f"{i+1} von {totalFiles} Dateien bearbeitet!")

    word.Quit()
```

Comment: That script sounds interesting. Is it available somewhere? Its hard to guess without viewing the code, but this seems like a good candidate for multiprocessing. Also, if you are using a traditional spinning hard drive (and have 2 of them), writing to a different disk than reading can make a difference for large payloads like this. I'm not surprised at the numbers if you are doing these serially.

Comment: yea i thought about doing multiprocessing... but i only got 4 cores here, and even 4 times the speed would be still kinda slow so i didnt try yet :D

Comment: Multiprocessing won't help because the real work is performed by Word, not Python. You can start 4 instances of Word instead but, as win32com doesn't have async operations, it's tricky. Perhaps a better option would be to use the `wordconv` utility [as shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996949/word-file-converter) to convert the files from a shell. They'll still be in Compatibility mode though. You can use Powershell's Parallel-ForEach to use multiple instances of `wordconv` to process all files. You may be able to use more than 4 as part of the operation IO bound

Comment: Yea, im dont know if using word for the conversion makes it significant slower too. Even if you ignore the missing multithreading.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - How so? Office generally uses a single threaded apartment model. The only way to get parallel conversion is multiple processes. I don't see how "work is performed by word, not python" means that you can only do the work serially.

Answer (score 1):

As other commenters have suggested **wordconv** seems to be a good solution and much faster than using win32com. For ~1700 files transfer time was ~389 seconds or about **~.21 seconds per object**. This time largely can depend on your system hardware since it is involving a lot of read and write operations as well as some processing power for the conversion. I basically maxed out 16GB of ram and an old 6th gen i7. Using a HDD probably will slow it down a lot. Even at .21 seconds per object it's going to take like 70 hours (if it's similar to the speed on my machine). But it's a vast improvement of 1-2 second per object which is 10x as long.

I use `subprocess.Popen()` to run the command `C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\Wordconv.exe -oice -nme srcfile dstfile` in the for loop.

Although the recommended way to invoke a subprocess is [subprocess.run()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) I used `subprocess.Popen()` because it won't wait for the process to finish before continuing. There might be a way to do this with subprocess.run as well but I'm not familiar enough with it to say. (maybe someone can provide feedback on that)

```
import os
import subprocess
from timeit import default_timer as timer



def convert_doc_to_docx():
    
    src_dir = r"c:\Users\myuser\test"
    out_dir = "c:\\Users\\myuser\\test\\dst\\"
    all_files = [name for name in os.listdir(src_dir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(src_dir, name))]
    file_count = len(all_files)

    # change according to where "WordConv.exe" is located on your system
    path_to_wordconv = "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\Wordconv.exe"

    print(f"Source dir file count: {file_count}")
    start = timer()
    for file in all_files:
        in_file_path = os.path.join(src_dir, file)
        out_file_path = out_dir + file + "x"

        # this will get process intensive 
        subprocess.Popen([f"{path_to_wordconv}","-oice","-nme",f"{in_file_path}",f"{out_file_path}"])
        
    end = timer()

    count_output_dir = len([name for name in os.listdir(out_dir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(out_dir, name))])    
    elapsed_time = end-start
    time_object = elapsed_time / count_output_dir

  
    print(f"Elapsed time: {elapsed_time} second")
    print(f"Time per object: {time_object} second")
    


    return
       

convert_doc_to_docx()
```

##### Output

```
Source dir file count: 1728
Elapsed time: 369.7448267 second
Time per object: 0.21397270063657406 second
```